# position absolute ruined my next section image background

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, html, css

i am working on a one page website ,and i am having problem with the background-attachment:fixed ,the problem is that the background image is get ruined when i scroll down check the image http://www4.0zz0.com/2015/08/21/05/772542239.jpg this is the code:

```
<section id="home" class="home home-fullscreen"><div class="container"><div class="intro"><div class="start">T-Link Computer Systems is a leading Information Technology Solution provider. </div>
        <h1 class=" wow bounce">T-LINK COMPUTER SYSTEMS</h1>
        <div class="start">We are committed to continuing value and pursuit of client satisfaction</div></div></div>

        <div class="masked">
            <div style="width:100%; height:100%;">
              <video width="1920" height="1080" id="bgvid" src="img/newcomputer.mov" poster="img/videoPlaceholder1.png"  autoplay loop >
                <source src="img/newcomputer.mp4" type="video/mp4">
                <!--
                <source src="img/new computer.webm" type="video/webm">
                <source src="img/new computer.ogg" type="video/ogg">-->
              </video>
            </div>
        </div>
        <a href="#services">
    <div class="scroll-down">
        <span>
            <i class="fa fa-angle-double-down fa-4x"></i>
        </span>
    </div>
    </a>
    </section>
```

the css code

```
    video { position:absolute;
  right:  0;
  bottom: 0;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  min-width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  z-index: -100;
  background-image:url(../img/background.jpg);
  background-position:center;
  background-size:cover;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;

}

.nav > li > a{
    font-weight: normal;
}

.navbar-smak {
    background: rgba(20, 51, 102, 0.2);
    transition: all 0.5s;
}

.navbar-smak .nav {
    padding: 25px 0;
}

.navbar-small {
    background: rgba(20, 51, 102, 1);
}

.navbar-small .nav {
    padding: 5px 0 !important;
}

.navbar-small .navbar-brand > img {
    height: 40px;
}

.navbar-small .navbar-brand {
    padding: 5px 15px 0 0;
}

.nav > li > a {
    padding: 0;
}

.navbar-brand > img {
    height: 60px;
}

.navbar-nav > li > a {
    color: #fff;
}

.nav .open > a, .nav .open > a:hover, .nav .open > a:focus,
.navbar-nav > li.active > a {
    color: #00E1FF;
    background: transparent;
}

.navbar-nav > li > .dropdown-menu {
    margin-top: -5px;;
    border-top-right-radius: 4px;
    border-top-left-radius: 4px;
}

.home {
    /*background: url(../img/videoPlaceholder.png) no-repeat top fixed;*/
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
    background-size: auto !100%;
}


.navbar-nav > li > a:hover {
    background-color: transparent;
    color: #00E1FF;
}

.navbar-nav > li > a:before {
    content: "\f0c8";
    margin: 0 15px;
    font-family: "FontAwesome";
    font-size: 5px;
    line-height: 42px;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    color:transparent;
}
.navbar-nav > li:first-child > a:before{
    content: " ";
    padding: 0;
}

.masked {
    background: rgba(123, 38, 130, 0.3);
    background-image: url('../img/patern.png');
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: block;}
.intro {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    top: 50%;
    left: 0;
    text-align: center;
    -webkit-transform: translate(0%, -50%);
       -moz-transform: translate(0%, -50%);
        -ms-transform: translate(0%, -50%);
         -o-transform: translate(0%, -50%);
            transform: translate(0%, -50%);
    padding: 0 15px;
}

.intro h1{
    font-weight: 800;
    font-size:80px;
    color: rgba(20, 51, 102, 1);
    text-shadow: -1px -1px 0 #366A8E, 1px -1px 0 #366A8E, -1px 1px 0 #366A8E, 1px 1px 0 #366A8E;
}
.start{
    font-size:30px;}

    @media (max-width: 767px) {
        .intro h1{
    font-weight: 800;
    font-size:50px;
    color: rgba(20, 51, 102, 1);
    text-shadow: -1px -1px 0 #366A8E, 1px -1px 0 #366A8E, -1px 1px 0 #366A8E, 1px 1px 0 #366A8E;
}
.start{
    font-size:16.5px;}}
```

i found out that the problem of the background-attachment is fixed when i remove the position:absolute; from the video tag ,but the problem is that the masked goes in that case and it disappear, how to fix the background issue plus keep the pattern masked above the video background
and for the other problem how to fix the gray background in the nav menu when u click on the anchor tag (check the image the green arrow)
thanks for helping in advance.

Comment: can you create a fiddle ?

Comment: no i am so sorry i can't

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/TylerH/0touvt3y/ I have created a fiddle @RajeevChowdaryGurram

Comment: Rajeev Chowdary Gurram are u there ?